# Where Is the Java SELinux Policy Module for CentOS 7?

Tags: java, linux, selinux

I noticed that in the targeted SELinux policy for CentOS 7, there is no `java.pp` file in the

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules
```

directory. Interestingly enough, in the source rpm `selinux-policy-3.12.1-153.el7.src.rpm`
 from http://vault.centos.org, there are java.te, java.if, and java.fc, files, so I tried to get a java.pp by copying them in a seperate folder and running:

```
make NAME=targeted -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile
```

but I get an error `74:ERROR 'unknown type java_domain'`and no java.pp file.

Does anyone the state of Java ans SELinux for CentOS 7. I noticed that my CentOS 6.5 servers have a java.pp module available.

Thanks,
greenaj

Answer (score 1):

I just started looking at this myself and found:

https://github.com/TresysTechnology/refpolicy-contrib

Git clone the above and notice java.te, java.if, and java.fc

Try:
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile java.pp

If the make succeeds, load the new module via:
semodule -i java.pp

I actually get a /usr/bin/checkmodule syntax error on java.te,
but I'm trying this on RHEL 6.7 ...

May need to checkout a specific branch for one's OS-release.
Good luck.